# Counter that auto updates for total items from firebase database Kotlin Android

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, count

I have a quiz application and I need to implement a method where when I add a new question, a new field in the database is automatically added and updated. I would like it to read the value in db for it the first time and afterwards, increase it by +1 and save it in the same field

I'm a beginner in kotlin android and I don't know exactly how things work. That is why I am waiting for some suggestions and explanations, and i hope i am not asking for too much.

Thank you for your time and patience!

MY CODE:

```
    private fun newQuestionCount() {
        val countRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/$sessionId/count")
        val arr = arrayListOf<Int>()

        countRef.addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener{
            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                if(p0.exists()){
                    val value = p0.getValue(QuestionCountClass::class.java)

                    if (value != null) {
                        arr.add(value.totalItems)
                    }

                }
            }
            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

            }
        })

        addOne(arr.first())

    }

    private fun addOne(value: Int) {
        val countRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/$sessionId/count")
        val newVal = value + 1

        countRef.setValue(newVal)

    }

class QuestionCountClass( val totalItems: Int) {
    constructor() : this(0)
}
```

[My database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ES8nX.jpg)

The crash details:

```
2019-09-20 21:06:23.056 19824-19824/com.x.quizapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.x.quizapp, PID: 19824
    java.util.NoSuchElementException: List is empty.
        at kotlin.collections.CollectionsKt___CollectionsKt.first(_Collections.kt:196)
        at com.x.quizapp.MainActivity.newQuestionCount(MainActivity.kt:91)
        at com.x.quizapp.MainActivity.newQuestion(MainActivity.kt:56)
        at com.x.quizapp.MainActivity.access$newQuestion(MainActivity.kt:17)
        at com.x.quizapp.MainActivity$onCreate$1.onClick(MainActivity.kt:27)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Comment: Please expand for example `1312` object and show us wthat is the exact property that you want to update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several good hours of work, I decided to go back to an earlier version and to start again. Apparently every time I was wrong about the same thing. In the end, I managed to make it work. I'll post the solution if anyone else needs it.

```
   private fun newQuestionCount() {
    val countRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/$sessionId/count")

    countRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object: ValueEventListener{
        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
            if(p0.exists()){
                val value = p0.getValue().toString()
                    addOne(value)
            }
        }
        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {}
    })
}

private fun addOne(value: String) {
    val countRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/$sessionId/count")
    val newVal = value.toInt()+1

    countRef.setValue(newVal)

}
```

I don't realize how correct it is, but it works quite well.